# Finding distance bettween all connected points (intersections) in a network (on a line) without k-nearest

Tags: qgis, distance, network

I am quite new to QGIS so I was wondering whether it is possible to find the distance between all points in a network, such that the distance between each one is determined by whether they are connected by the road network rather than k-nearest as the distances vary and are not indicative of whether they are both connected by a line. Heres an image of my problem:
[image]

So in this case, for example, if I were to find the distance to all connected points for 161, I would get distance such that: 66-->161, 128-->161 and 133-->161 (which cant be done with k-nearest)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the roads network consists of linestrings that start exactly at a node and end exactly at a node, the connected points and the distances-by-road can be found using a virtual layer.

The following SQL statement assumes that the point layer is called "points" and the road layer is called "roads", and both have some identifier column called "id":

```
WITH roadpts AS (
  SELECT p.id AS ptid, r.id AS roadid, ST_Length(r.geometry) AS dist
  FROM "points" AS p
  JOIN "roads" AS r
    ON ST_Within(p.geometry, ST_Boundary(r.geometry))
)
SELECT a.ptid AS pt_a, b.ptid AS pt_b, a.roadid, a.dist
FROM roadpts AS a
JOIN roadpts AS b
  ON a.roadid = b.roadid AND a.ptid <> b.ptid
```

Some explanation:

- in CTE "roadpts" the points are joined with the roads, where any point from "points" must lie `ST_Within` the boundary (i.e. either the startpoint or the endpoints) of any road
- the length of a linestring equals the distance between startpoint and endpoint
- in the main query the table is self-joined, based on the road id, excluding self-joins on point id

Comment: Thanks for your response! I was just wondering why the resulting table is completely blank. What could cause this since all of my lines (between each node) are separate elements on the same layer could this be the reason?

Comment: That could very well be the reason, or one of multiple possible reasons. Could you describe the table structure of the layer?